# Lifetime problem calling sort_unstable_by_key()

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to call [`Vec::sort_unstable_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_unstable_by_key) on a `Vec`. This example is simplified; I realize I could use `sort_unstable()`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<String> = Default::default();
    vec.sort_unstable_by_key(|k| k);
}
```

but I get:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:34
  |
7 |     vec.sort_unstable_by_key(|k| k);
  |                               -- ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                               ||
  |                               |return type of closure is &'2 String
  |                               has type `&'1 String`
```

I'm not sure why `k`'s lifetime and the closure return value's lifetime aren't self-evidently the same, but I tried to fix it by providing a separate function that spells out the lifetimes:

```
fn get_key<'a>(entry: &'a String) -> &'a String {
    entry
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<String> = Default::default();
    vec.sort_unstable_by_key(get_key);
}
```

but then I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/main.rs:8:9
     |
8    |     vec.sort_unstable_by_key(get_key);
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
     |
     = note: expected associated type `<for<'a> fn(&'a String) -> &'a String {get_key} as FnOnce<(&String,)>>::Output`
                found associated type `<for<'a> fn(&'a String) -> &'a String {get_key} as FnOnce<(&String,)>>::Output`
     = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
```

The expected and found types are identical, but "the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime". I'm not sure what this means. Why doesn't this work?